# WCF Async CTP Silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-5.0, async-ctp

Briefly,

Visual studio 2012 RC **Silverlight 5 Application** consumes *Game* **WCF 4 Service** hosted in **ASP.net 4 Application** with ChannelFactory technique via Shared **Portable Library .NET4/SL5** contains the *iGame* interface with **Async CTP**

**Graph :**
ASP.NET **<=** Class Library ( Game ) **<=** Portable Library ( iGame ) **=>** Silverlight

**Portable Library**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface iGame
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<bool> Request ( string Key );
}
```

**Class Library**

```
[ServiceBehavior ( InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode . Single , ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode . Multiple , UseSynchronizationContext = true )]
public class Game : iGame
{
    public async Task<bool> Request ( string Key )
    {
        return await Task . Factory . StartNew ( ( ) => true );
    }
}
```

**Silverlight**

```
    private async void myButton_Click ( object sender , RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( await Messenger . Instance . Client . Request ( XXX . Text ) ) // Exception
            NavigationService . Navigate ( new Uri ( "/Views/YYY.xaml" , UriKind . Relative ) );
    }
```

- Messenger is a Singleton Class initiating and storing my Client proxy via ChannelFactory.

---

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The contract 'iGame' contains synchronous operations, which are not supported in Silverlight. Split the operations into "Begin" and "End" parts and set the AsyncPattern property on the OperationContractAttribute to 'true'. Note that you do not have to make the same change on the server.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)
```

**What**'s wrong ? O_o

Comment: Yes, Async CTP installed to all my solution assemblies, also there's no inner exceptions there :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your client side, your `iGame` proxy is *synchronous*, and you're using [fake-asynchronous wrappers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) around it to *pretend* it's asynchronous.

You need an asynchronous proxy. You may be able to do this by having VS2012RC regenerate the proxy, or you may be able to [use `TaskWsdlImportExtension`](http://www.larswilhelmsen.com/2010/11/05/taskwsdlimportextensiona-hidden-gem-in-the-c-vnext-async-ctp-samples/). I'm not sure if either solution will work in a portable library just yet.

Comment: No, let's assume async techniques as TAP, EAP, ARM. The TaskWsdkImportExtension will create APM and TAP instead of APM and EAP. But I'm initially using TAP

Comment: According to the code you posted, your `Game` class inherits from `iGame`, and uses `StartNew` to treat a synchronous call as though it were asynchronous. If your code is different than what you posted, then please post the actual code you're using.

Comment: This's my code, I also try to graph my solution to be clear for SOers.

Comment: You misunderstand me, I'm using Task-based Asynchronous Pattern and you're suggesting using TaskWsdkImportExtension which converts other patterns to TAP! Please read my code carefully.

Comment: OK, let's take it one step at a time, then. How do you use `Task<bool>` as a return type for a WCF 4, since [`async` support won't be added until WCF 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/13/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-async-await.aspx)?

Comment: I've been assuming that you have a working .NET server/client and were adding Silverlight support. If you're writing both client and server right now, you'd probably want to read [Async WCF Today and Tomorrow](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html).

Comment: Ok, I'm talking about Tomorrow part in your link, but I'm coding ChannelFactory client not generating it.

Comment: Also I tested generating client and the generating service reference is written with ARM pattern. Is there any way to go TAP on both sides!

Comment: If you're using WCF 4, you'll need to expose it as APM (`AsyncPattern`) - you can't return `Task`.

Comment: I'm checking yours as answer but my last question, from tutorials I read the Async CTP is supported under SL5 and .NET4 with the nuget package launched, true or false :(

Comment: "Supported" is a strong term for a Community Technology *Preview*. It was supported quite well until VS2012 Dev Preview came out - since that time, the async team has focused on the async code actually going out into production instead of working on VS2010+AsyncCTP. I expect that shortly after VS2012 RTMs, the Async CTP will be dropped. This will leave you with two options for `async` code (.NET 4.5 and the Async Targeting Pack for .NET 4.0), both options requiring VS2012. So I do expect them to drop `async` support for VS2010, but you will be able to do `async` for .NET 4.0 using VS2012.